# PKG_CONFIG_PATH cairo.pc cannot find pixman

Tags: package-management, node.js

following this instruction: http://npmjs.org/package/canvas

i have installed cairo and pixman, but cairo cannot find pixman.

```
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pixman-1' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
```

my cairo.pc looks like this:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: cairo
Description: Multi-platform 2D graphics library
Version: 1.12.14

Requires.private:   gobject-2.0 glib-2.0      pixman-1 >= 0.30.0    fontconfig >= 2.2.95 freetype2 >= 9.7.3   libpng xrender >= 0.6 x11
xext
Libs: -L${libdir} -lcairo
Libs.private:           -lz -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}/cairo
```

now look what happens when i edit PKG_CONFIG_PATH...

with:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig



[root@vps ~]# npm install canvas
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas

> canvas@1.0.3 install /lib/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pixman-1' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/root/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:415:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:786:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab065.3
gyp ERR! command "node" "/root/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /lib/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! canvas@1.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab065.3
npm ERR! command "node" "/root/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! cwd /lib
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /lib/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

or:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig



[root@vps ~]# npm install canvas
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas

> canvas@1.0.3 install /node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/node_modules/canvas/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value>    Canvas::StreamJPEGSync(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../src/Canvas.cc:369: warning: passing ‘double’ for argument 2 to ‘void    write_to_jpeg_stream(cairo_surface_t*, int, int, closure_t*)’
../src/Canvas.cc:369: warning: passing ‘double’ for argument 3 to ‘void     write_to_jpeg_stream(cairo_surface_t*, int, int, closure_t*)’
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.o
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Context2d::DrawImage(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:639: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:640: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:641: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:642: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:643: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:644: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:645: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:646: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:650: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:651: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:652: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:653: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:657: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:658: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:679: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘float’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:680: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘float’
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc: In static member function ‘static void Context2d::SetShadowBlur(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)’:
../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc:942: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/color.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Image.o
../src/Image.cc: In member function ‘cairo_status_t Image::loadGIFFromBuffer(uint8_t*, unsigned int)’:
../src/Image.cc:602: error: ‘cairo_format_stride_for_width’ was not declared in this scope
../src/Image.cc: In member function ‘cairo_status_t Image::decodeJPEGIntoSurface(jpeg_decompress_struct*)’:
../src/Image.cc:716: error: ‘cairo_format_stride_for_width’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Image.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/node_modules/canvas/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:786:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab065.3
gyp ERR! command "node" "/root/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! canvas@1.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab065.3
npm ERR! command "node" "/root/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: @tjholowaychuk in this (https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/74) page you say: 'the absence of cairo_format_stride_for_width() tells me you need a newer cairo'. my cairo is version 1.12.14. that was 2 years ago how can i fix this?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. The command that fails is this: `pkg-config pixman-1 --libs` saying it can't find pixman-1.pc which is in the directory mentioned in the message `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: I'm going through this again now it's october, where is pixman-1.pc?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your question I found my solution.

```
[server]$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/test
[server]$ make
[server]$ make install
[server]$ ls -R ~/test/
~/test/:
include  lib

~/test/include:
pixman-1

~/test/include/pixman-1:
pixman-version.h  pixman.h

~/test/lib:
libpixman-1.a   libpixman-1.so    libpixman-1.so.0.32.4
libpixman-1.la  libpixman-1.so.0  pkgconfig

~/test/lib/pkgconfig:
pixman-1.pc
```

All I required was

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/lib/pkgconfig/"
```

then ***pkg-config pixman-1 --libs*** returned the correct library and I could get cairo to compile.

---

Perhaps there is a problem with pkg-config finding pixman: you could try setting the environment variables to override pkg-config

> pixman_CFLAGS - C compiler flags for pixman, overriding pkg-config
>
> pixman_LIBS - linker flags for pixman, overriding pkg-config

```
$ export pixman_CFLAGS="-I$HOME/include/pixman-1"
$ export pixman_LIBS="-L$HOME/lib/ -lpixman-1"
```

---

[Another Problem/Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570505/having-problems-building-cairo-on-x64-centos)

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy **pixman.h** and **pixman-version.h** from ***pixman-1*** folder into upper folder which is ***include***.

Now you can run **make** command and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the pixman dev libraries - which these instructions seem to have left out.

`# apt-get install libpixman-1-dev`

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on Debian and installing the required packages (`build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev`) didn't fix it. Eventually I figured out that switching the versions of python and node that I'm running fixed it. It did not play nice with Python 3.9 or Node 15. Here's the working configuration:

```
> python --version
Python 3.8.6
> node -v
v14.15.4
> npm -v
6.14.11
```